# Page size equal to the size of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a problem with `Modal jQuery` and `iframe`.
The page size within the `iframe` is less than half of the `iframe`.

Is there any way that my webpage will occupy full `height` `width` of the `iframe` ?

Below is my `code`:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var dialog = $("#dialog");
    var openModal = $("#btnLupa");

    dialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    dialog.load(function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

    var AbrirModal = function (url, title, width, height) {
        dialog.dialog("option", "width", width);
        dialog.dialog("option", "height", height);
        dialog.dialog("option", "title", title);
        dialog.attr("src", url, width);
    }

</script>
```

And below is the structure withing the `iframe`

```
<iframe id="dialog" class="ui-helper-hidden noScrolling"></iframe>
    <tr>
        <td class="label_right" nowrap>Contrato&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="num_contrato" value="" size="15" maxlength="17" tabindex="1" OnKeyPress="javascript:MascAlfaNum()" OnKeyDown="TeclaEnter()" onchange="PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();">
            <!--<img id='' style='display:; cursor:hand' name='Pesquisa_Contrato' width='16' height='16' src='/gen/mid/lupa.gif' border='0' alt='Pesquisa Contrato' onClick="javascript:AbrePesquisa('/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp?ind_situacao=&tipo_empresa=&ind_classificacao=&p_cod_tipo_contrato=&indsubmit=false&txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&ind_tipo_pessoa=J&funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&abre_modal=S&ind_alteracao_contrato=&tipo_preco=','Pesquisa_Contrato','Pesquisa Contrato', 700, 500, 20, 15, 'S')">-->
            <img id='btnLupa' style='display:; cursor:hand' name='Pesquisa_Contrato' width='16' height='16' src='/gen/mid/lupa.gif' border='0' alt='Pesquisa Contrato' onclick='AbrirModal("../../ace/ace005a.asp?/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp$$ind_situacao=&tipo_empresa=&ind_classificacao=&p_cod_tipo_contrato=&indsubmit=false&txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&ind_tipo_pessoa=J&funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&abre_modal=S&ind_alteracao_contrato=&tipo_preco=", "Pesquisa Contrato", 700, 500)'>
            <input type="text"  name="nome_contrato" value="" size="50" tabindex="-1" Readonly class="camposblocks">
            <input type="hidden" name="cod_ts_contrato" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ind_tipo_pessoa" value="J" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

See this is how the page inside the `iframe` in `browser` appears

[image]

I would like that the page will fill the `iframe`.
Please help me into this.

Comment: in this the size of iframe is looking small

Comment: @SarthakSharma, the size iframe: width="700px" and height="500px"

Comment: the problem is the Modal Window and not the IFrame, i think.

Comment: Do you have a live example of it ??

Comment: Yes, the image above. Inside the IFrame is half or less of the Modal Window.